# Nginx symlinks not indexing

Tags: ubuntu, symlink, nginx

I'm running nginx 1.10.0  on Ubuntu 16.04

Nginx dos not follow symlinks. it even not list the symlink in directory index:
[image]

as you see in the image `wgi` is a symlink and it doesn't list in directory index.

and I get 404 error when I check `localhost/wgi`

here is my nginx.conf:

```
http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

disable_symlinks off;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 5;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and here is my sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

autoindex on;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    autoindex on;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php7.0-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

I see some solutions about set `disable_symlinks` to `off` and symlink permissions but it doesn't work for me.

thanks for your advise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I re-install Nginx and now it recognize symlinks

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.